# Filtering out duplicate entires for older rows

Tags: java, sql, hana

There's 2 tables;

- OITM that references an Item's information and stock amounts
- OINM that references all changes to all Item's stock amounts.

Currently, I've already built a SQL that lets me SELECT new changes to Item stock by joining the tables, but I've run into the issue that sometimes there's duplicate entries, when OINM had two changes to the same Item.

This is the SQL i currently have is as follows:

```
SELECT T0.\"ItemCode\", T0.\"WhsCode\", T0.\"OnHand\", T0.\"IsCommited\", T0.\"OnOrder\", T1.\"DocDate\", T1.\"DocTime\" 
FROM KA_DEV6.OITW T0,KA_DEV6.OINM T1 
WHERE T0.\"WhsCode\" = '01' AND T0.\"ItemCode\" = T1.\"ItemCode\" 
AND (T1.\"DocDate\" > '2019-10-20' OR (T1.\"DocDate\" = '2019-10-20' AND T1.\"DocTime\" >= '1025'))
```

This outputs the following result:

```
|ItemCode:CC01.NB.C.LF.F.LI.V.0813.GRCE|WhsCode:01|OnHand:8.000000|IsCommited:4.000000|OnOrder:0.000000|DocDate:2019-10-22 00:00:00.000000000|DocTime:1024
|ItemCode:JO.C.LF.U.LI.V.0004. 22.NG|WhsCode:01|OnHand:1.000000|IsCommited:0.000000|OnOrder:0.000000|DocDate:2019-10-21 00:00:00.000000000|DocTime:1223
|ItemCode:JO.I.FT.M.AB.C.0106.  L.NG|WhsCode:01|OnHand:32.000000|IsCommited:0.000000|OnOrder:0.000000|DocDate:2019-10-21 00:00:00.000000000|DocTime:1401
|ItemCode:JO.I.FT.M.AB.C.0106.  L.NG|WhsCode:01|OnHand:38.000000|IsCommited:0.000000|OnOrder:0.000000|DocDate:2019-10-21 00:00:00.000000000|DocTime:1402
```

The issue is that there are entries that have the same ItemCode, and I only need the most recent change. (Thus, I'd need to filter out the 3rd result, only returning the most recent which is 4th.)

How could I go about this? Because my ordering is by 2 fields (DocDate and DocTime), and then filter out the duplicates.

Ordering is already something i can do and works which is adding

```
ORDER BY T1.\"DocDate\", T1.\"DocTime\" ASC
```

But how do i filter out duplicates?

Expected output would be:

```
|ItemCode:CC01.NB.C.LF.F.LI.V.0813.GRCE|WhsCode:01|OnHand:8.000000|IsCommited:4.000000|OnOrder:0.000000|DocDate:2019-10-22 00:00:00.000000000|DocTime:1024
|ItemCode:JO.C.LF.U.LI.V.0004. 22.NG|WhsCode:01|OnHand:1.000000|IsCommited:0.000000|OnOrder:0.000000|DocDate:2019-10-21 00:00:00.000000000|DocTime:1223
|ItemCode:JO.I.FT.M.AB.C.0106.  L.NG|WhsCode:01|OnHand:38.000000|IsCommited:0.000000|OnOrder:0.000000|DocDate:2019-10-21 00:00:00.000000000|DocTime:1402
```

Regards

EDIT: For anyone reading in the future, and checking out the answer, do note that for my case, the actual ordering of the information didnt matter, since i dont care about it being the newst change, only filtering out duplicates. For the actual most recent table, you need to change the Order By clause from the sub query to `ORDER BY T1.\"DocDate\",T1.\"DocTime\" DESC` and optionally, at the end of the entire query again to order the results.

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

 Try create a sample in http://rextester.com

Comment: Added expected output. DB Schema is irrelevant  (And over 200 fields big for each table) since i only need to work with the 3 fields mentioned (ItemCode, DocTime,DocDate) for this question.

I provided an example that should work as sample data, and current output.

Comment: You have to provide the sample data and expected output. Is like you show me a cake and tell me to replicate but dont tell me what ingredients you use. And you can  provide a simplified schema of your problem. But schema help to see what index are you using what is the pk, what is the fk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the ROW_NUMBER windowing function to this like this:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM (
  SELECT T0.\"ItemCode\", T0.\"WhsCode\", T0.\"OnHand\", T0.\"IsCommited\",    T0.\"OnOrder\", T1.\"DocDate\", T1.\"DocTime\",
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY   T0.\"ItemCode\" ORDER BY  T1.\"DocTime\" DESC) AS RN
  FROM KA_DEV6.OITW T0
  JOIN KA_DEV6.OINM T1 ON T0.\"WhsCode\" = '01' AND T0.\"ItemCode\" = T1.\"ItemCode\"
  WHERE  T1.\"DocDate\" > '2019-10-20' OR (T1.\"DocDate\" = '2019-10-20' AND T1.\"DocTime\" >= '1025')
) X
WHERE RN = 1
```

Note -- I also used standard join syntax not the 20+ year old syntax you were using.